# Ora 03135 error in pl sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to refresh DB objects through spool file and it takes more than one hour to complete and the plsql window don't close and it gives this error :

```
Ora 03135
```

plsql developer runs from windows server and I checked the sqlnet.ora file and I could not find any timeout parameters .

Comment: Do you have SQL*Plus installed?

Comment: yes and it runs from windows server

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your installation.  You would be better off asking your question on AA's dedicated support site: http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html